# How do I get the selected Value from dynamically created CheckBox?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, checkbox, foreach

I added CheckBox controls dynamically from the database to FlowLayOutPanel. How do I get and store all selected values?

My sample code is here...

```
private void dynamicCheck()
{
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
    DataSet1TableAdapters.tbl_subjects1TableAdapter ta = 
        new DataSet1TableAdapters.tbl_subjects1TableAdapter();
    DataTable dt = ta.GetData();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
        chk.Width = 90;
        chk.Text = row[1].ToString();
        chk.CheckedChanged += new 
                          EventHandler(changeCheck);
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(chk);            
    }
}   

private void changeCheck(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
    CheckBox chk = sender as CheckBox;
    if (chk.Checked)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("checked item" + chk.Text);        
    }
}

private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: What is the difficulty, the problem or the error? What is the question? What do you want to do? Save what? Where? How? Do you ask for a thing like `MyPanel.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(Checked)`? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) • [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) • [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) • [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question)

Comment: Sorry for the question. I want to get checkBox check value and store as a list and create sql insert query of each value of the list.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this:

```
private List<CheckBox> _checkBoxes = null;

private void DynamicCheck()
{
    DataSet1TableAdapters.tbl_subjects1TableAdapter ta =
        new DataSet1TableAdapters.tbl_subjects1TableAdapter();
    DataTable dt = ta.GetData();
    
    _checkBoxes = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row =>
    {
        CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
        chk.Width = 90;
        chk.Text = row[1].ToString();
        chk.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(changeCheck);
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(chk);
        return chk;
    }).ToList();
}
```

Now you can access each `CheckBox` in `_checkBoxes`.